# removeWithCompletionHandler causes logging out of Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

I am using GKTurnBasedMatch's removeWithCompletionHandler to programmatically remove old (finished, i.e., with status = GKTurnBasedMatchStatusEnded) turn-based matches from Game Center when needed (to avoid extra loading burden, I want to keep the amount of finished matches to a minimum).
I am getting no error and the match is correctly removed.
However, most times I do this, my user gets kicked out of Game Center, so the local player is no longer authenticated. This happens on iOS7, with both iPhone and iPad.

Did anyone experience this? Is there any way around it?

NB: I might as well not remove matches from GC, as I use internal business logic to determine which matches should be listed to the user and show, say, only the 10 (unfinished) most recent ones. However, I am afraid that hundreds of games might be kept in GC and that this might slow down interactions with GC when I have to list ongoing matches.

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling removeWithCompletionHandler inside of a completion handler for another Game Center API call then you might be experiencing the very same issue that's been plaguing me for a while. The solution I tried today involves simply delaying the call to removeWithCompletionHandler for a few seconds, like so:

```
[match performSelector:@selector(removeWithCompletionHandler:) withObject:^(NSError *error) { /* callback code here */ } afterDelay:3.0];
```

For me, this worked great but meant I had to rework a few things in relation to displaying active games... so be wary of that if this solution works for you. Also, it's worth noting that the 3 second delay is an arbitrary value I picked and it worked for me.

In my case, I was calling removeWithCompletionHandler inside the completion handler block for the various quit methods on GKTurnBasedMatch.

I imagine there is some issue on Game Center's end where the two requests cannot be made so close together without resulting in such woe. This is evidenced by the fact that the issue did not ever occur for me when I slowly stepped through the calls to Game Center.

**EDIT**

Here's some cool news; seems like they've fixed the bug in iOS 8. I built an app which demonstrates the bug for bug-reporting purposes (originally for iOS 7). I've tested that same app running in iOS 8 and it seems that the bug has been squashed.

Finally.

IMO, you should consider adding the removeWithCompletionHandler call in now.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this workaround (+1). Yet, it's somehow discomforting that, although using completion handlers, one needs to wait even longer an in a completely arbitrary and unjustified way. And yes, I was also doing this inside the blocks for the various quit methods... My take now is to not remove anything, and hope that GC will at some point automatically remove some of the completed matches.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Oh, just a heads up on that last point: with the project I'm working on at the moment, I originally was not removing the games and just leaving them in GC, and it did not go well. Eventually I was unable to start new games and I figured out it was because there were too many sitting "open" (even if the player had quit) in GC. It was just as difficult to debug, since there were no errors coming back from the GC API then either. All round, pretty disappointed in the GC API... But yeh, I'd suggest not leaving it up to GC.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Moose !! This problem had been bothering me for quite some time now